# While loop doesn't update real time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote this code using python for raspberry pi. But I am struggling with the code. The while loop doesn't break.

```
w=1
z=0

def auto_1(w,z):
    w=1
    z=0
    return w,z

def manual_1(w,z):
    w=0
    z=1
    return w,z

GPIO.add_event_detect(Manual, GPIO.RISING, callback=lambda *i: manual_1(w,z), bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_detect(Auto, GPIO.RISING, callback=lambda *i: auto_1(w,z), bouncetime=300)

while w==1:
      print("Auto")
      pfr_mains_1(PFRMains,PFRGen,GenStartOut,MainsCont,GenCont)
      pfr_mains_0(PFRMains,PFRGen,GenStartOut,MainsCont,GenCont)
      time.sleep(3)
      if w==0:
         break
```

The while loop doesn't break even though the "manual" event detected. The code runs fine but the loop does not break when an event detected. It seems the w value does not get updated from the initial value. But I have no clue what to do. Please help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: How do you expect `w` to change? You just use it as a parameter for a function call in the loop.

Comment: without an initial variable declaration it gives the error massage that the w and z is not defined. That is why I gave it an initial condition. I am no python expert. So I dont how else to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your main script body is using the global variable w. However, the two functions you defined have each their own local variable w. Anything these functions do to w stays inside the respective function.

You *could* declare w as global in both functions to always access the global w, but that's not really good practice. It would be better to assign the functions' result to the global w.

Comment: The problem solved. I assigned the variables as global variables and now it works fine. Thank you very much for the clear that up for me.

Comment: I wouldn't say "problem solved". Using `global` is a dirty way and you might get more problems later.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am looking for a better way of writing the code. Lets see how it goes.